# Can't we pass comma separated column numbers to yadcf init function to set filter

Tags: datatables-1.10, yadcf

**DataTables 1.10.13** **YADCF 0.9.3**

> Ajax data.

On load I'm calling following function:-

> columnDataType= columnd data type to set filter type
>
> columns = to get column title to set label
>
> table = table object to init yadcf plugin

```
function addFilter(columnDataType,columns,table){
var col = "";
var type="";
var label = "";
for(var i=0;i<columnDataType.length;i++){
    if(columnDataType[i]=="Character"){
        col = i;
        type = "text";
for(var index=0;index<columns.length;index++){
    if(i==index)
        label = "Select "+columns[i].title;
}
        
    
yadcf.init(table, [{
                        column_number: col,
                        filter_type: type,
                        filter_default_label : label
                    }]);
} else if(columnDataType[i]=="Number"){
        col = i;
        type = "range_number";
    
yadcf.init(table, [{
                        column_number: col,
                        filter_type: type
                    }]);
} else if(columnDataType[i]=="Date"){
        col = i;
        type = "date";
        label = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
    
yadcf.init(table, [{
                        column_number: col,
                        filter_type: type,
                        moment_date_format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy',
                        filter_default_label : label
                    }]);
}
}
```

}

> Above implementation giving **Cannot read property 'filter_delay' of undefined** error
>
> So, the scenario is that columns(no.,type) are dynamic,table might have multiple character columns for which I want to set text filter type, multiple date,number columns etc.So How to pass these column no.s to plugin like:-

```
yadcf.init(table, [{
                            column_number: col1,col2,col3,
                            filter_type: 'text',
                            filter_default_label : label
                        }]);
```

> OR

```
var col = [col1,col2,col3];
    yadcf.init(table, [{
                            column_number: col,
                            filter_type: 'text',
                            filter_default_label : label
                        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't init yadcf like that , each column filter definition should have its own object
you can create them in a loop and push into array which later can be passed to `yadcf.init` function